# Is there a way to sort the QGIS attribute table by date modified?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sorting, select-by-expression

I was wondering if there was a way to sort the attribute table in QGIS Pi by date modified. I have been digitizing a large area and I need to delete the last 50-100 features that were digitized. My current table has roughly 3,000 features on it and I really don't want to search through the map or attribute table to find them one by one.

Answer (score 3):

If your format is a geopackage, you can sort by fid and delete the rows with the highest fids as those are the last digitised.

Comment: You can also add a new field with the expression $id, which is format independent.